# Should dielectric constant be high or low for high-speed design? And why?

Tags: pcb-design, high-frequency, high-speed

I'm very confused that dielectric constant should be selected high or low to design high-speed boards.
It can be compared with FR4 material, dc ~4,6.

Comment: Which will slow signals more?

Comment: As I understand; if you choose high dielectric constant material, your signal will be slow.

Comment: @mrsaglam One doesn't even need to know anything but a smidgen of physics to answer this. High dielectric constants mean molecular structures that respond and polarize easily in response to the electric field. Which obviously means they interact. Which means they must slow it. Simple logic applied to one assumption. The why is the starting assumption.

Comment: @jonk Thats the good point! Math and physics really can answer almost everything.

Comment: @mrsaglam It can and does, always. Theory provides all meaning and is the only way we can even see anything, at all. (Without the theory of a sphere, we'd have no way to even observe curvature of the Earth or understand it.) The rest is just some minor details left to engineers to worry about and mop up afterwards. :) But some engineers don't realize their place and think otherwise. ;)

Comment: @mrsaglam I like the example your question makes. From my fortunate experiences working with some better ones, if a physicist walked into a room of engineers haggling over the meaning of equations they use or from experiences they possess, it's likely the physicist would just turn right around and leave in order to save themselves from the anguish of watching blind engineers knocking about the room with their white canes. To the physicist with eyes that see and a room well-lit by science theory, watching would be almost too painful to bear.

Answer (score 3):

> *I'm very confused that dielectric constant should be selected high or
> low to design high-speed boards.*

I'll try and answer your question by considering inter-chip communication speeds on a circuit board using copper tracks. With a higher dielectric constant and a given PCB track width, the capacitance will be higher and this inevitably means that the characteristic impedance of a track will be lower - this has a knock-on effect on speed. The [velocity factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_factor) (the ratio of actual signal propagation speed to the speed of light) is given by this equation: -

$$VF = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{μ_r ε_r}}$$

Pretty much all PCBs I've come across have μr = 1 (magnetic permeability) and so the equation effectively becomes: -

$$VF = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ε_r}}$$

So, with a higher electric permittivity (aka dielectric constant), the signal propagation speed relative to the speed of light (VF) lowers. In simple terms, the speed reduces.

So, if inter-chip communication speed is of importance you try and reduce the effects of a higher dielectric constant by making track widths smaller so there is less distributed capacitance along the track carrying the important signal.

Answer (score 1):

You choose a dielectric according to your other requirements.

Other requirements include

- packing density of board
- accuracy/constancy of dielectric constant
- whether low loss is needed

If you are making a high speed logic board, then generally loss and constancy are not too relevant. When you make a transmission line to get good propagation and control reflections, getting to within 10% or 20% of the target impedance is good enough. However, often on a high speed logic board, you also want good packing density. While a higher dielectric constant allows thinner lines for given impedance, reducing the height of the dielectric allows not only thinner lines but also smaller gaps between them, so there is no great driver to go for very high dielectric constants when thin layers are available. FR4 is almost universally used for its cost, and reasonable control of dielectric constant.

When lower loss and higher accuracy are needed, there are three principal ranges of dielectric available

- PTFE - Er around 2, low loss, soft
- Rogers 4350 - Er around 4.5, intended to be a 'better FR4', processes like FR4
- Alumina - Er around 10, and ceramic loaded plastics intended to be 'soft alumina'

In almost all cases, the choice between these is not made on dielectric constant *per se*, but on the other properties.

If you want to process like FR4, then use Rogers.

If you want to wire-bond, then you need a hard substrate like alumina.

If you want to make stripline by sandwiching layers together, something soft like PTFE will be best.